# Traversing disconnected graphs and creating indentifiers

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am trying to create a customer identity graph to track customers across devices, logged in or out.

Currently, I am trying to do two things:

1. For each disconnected graph, create mapping between unique generated
   key and entities (adobe, lead, account, checkout).

   1. For example, the bottom graph will randomly pick one of the entities to be used as the unique key. If we pick adobe, we will create a new value "adobe:<adobe_id>" and use that as the key to identify this disconnected graph. Perhaps we could traverse the entire disconnected graph and set the value "adobe:<adobe_id>" as a property.
2. (nice to have) Be able to handle
   situations where two different accounts may use the same ip_address.
   For example, the top graph should have 2 unique generated keys.

I'm fairly new to Gremlin but I understand the basics of graph traversal. Not sure where to start so any insights appreciated!

[image]

I've created a simplified version below. Gremlify link will allow code execution as well.

https://gremlify.com/jmg2fzo34om/3

Comment: i'm not sure i follow what you mean by "create mapping between unique generated key and entities" - could you please update your question to clarify that? perhaps a better understanding of the "generated key" would help me better understand part 2 of your question as well.

Comment: @stephenmallette thanks for the response. I've edited the post to hopefully clarify and provide an example.

Comment: i'm sorry, but it's still not completely clear. so, at least for item 1, are you just asking, how you would set a property with the same id to all the vertices in each disconnected graph to uniquely identify it? or are you trying to collect all the vertices for each disconnected graph into some kind of result?

Comment: Yup, the first requirement is setting the same unique id as a property in each disconnected graph to identify it. 
Eventually I would also like to collect all the vertices for each disconnected graph (including the newly set unique id) into a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are after some form of community detection or perhaps just trying to identify [components of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)). With Gremlin, this is likely best done with a [Graph Computer (OLAP)](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphcomputer) and perhaps the [`connectedComponent()` step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connectedcomponent-step):

```
gremlin> g.withComputer().
......1>   V().connectedComponent().
......2>         with(ConnectedComponent.propertyName, 'component').
......3>   elementMap().
......4>   order().by('component')
==>[id:0,label:account,component:0,account_id:1]
==>[id:2,label:lead,component:0,lead_id:1]
==>[id:6,label:account,component:0,account_id:3]
==>[id:8,label:checkout,checkout_id:1,component:0]
==>[id:10,label:lead,component:0,lead_id:2]
==>[id:12,label:ip_addr,component:0,ip_addr:1.1.1.1]
==>[id:16,label:page,page_id:1,component:14]
==>[id:18,label:lead,component:14,lead_id:4]
==>[id:4,label:adobe,component:14,adobe_id:1]
==>[id:14,label:ip_addr,component:14,ip_addr:3.3.3.3]
```

You can use Gremlin without Graph Computer (OLTP) to find connected components, but unless you have a really small graph it simply won't perform as well. If you are interested in learning more about that there is a Gremlin Recipe that goes into that subject in greater detail found [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#connected-components).

Comment: Thanks! One final minor request, would it be possible to sort the component by id asc?
So in that example, the second component would be 4 instead of 14.

You've been very helpful :)

Comment: No - not with the `connectedComponent()` step algorithm as it is.  It uses the first id it comes across and given the nature of GraphComputer/OLAP I don't think you can force it to deterministically hit the smallest id first. You might need your own modification of that `VertexProgram` to constantly adjust the "component" as it finds a smaller one. not sure if there is a better way offhand.

Comment: Looks like we are required to use AWS Neptune, so connectedComponent() is not compatible. Are there any alternatives? I looked into simplepath but it seems to have too many output records.

Comment: for neptune, at the moment, the best that can be offered for large graphs is to calculate this sort of thing outside of Neptune, i.e. export the data and process it with graphx, spark-gremlin, etc.